# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list but clearly the list contains it

Tags: python

Why am I getting the error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list` in the  code below? `85` is clearly in the gradebook list.

```
grades = [98, 97, 85, 88]
gradebook = [["physics", 98], ["calculus", 97], ["poetry", 85], ["history", 88]]
gradebook.remove(85)
```

Comment: `grades` contains 85.  `gradebook` does not.

Comment: Perhaps you want `gradebook = [k for k in gradebook if k[1] != 85]`.

Comment: *"85 is clearly in the gradebook list"* - no it is clearly not. On the other hand, `["poetry", 85]` is clearly in that list...

Answer (score 0):

`gradebook.remove(85)` would remove the element which value is 85.  gradebook contain sub-lists not integers.  Did you mean:

```
grades.remove(85)
```

or

```
gradebook = [ [subject,grade] for subject, grade in gradebook if grade != 85 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the modification you should be making **gradebook[nested_list_location].remove(your_int_value)** , since you are working with nested lists.

```
gradebook = [["physics", 98], ["calculus", 97], ["poetry", 85], ["history", 88]]
gradebook[-1].remove(88)
# will result in [['physics', 98], ['calculus', 97], ['poetry', 85], ['history']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
gradebook.remove(["poetry", 85])
```

When trying to remove an item, you need to provide `list[Union[str, int]]` because each of the elements in your list (`gradebook`) is of type `list[Union[str, int]]`